# Unable to update table using PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a php-script to update a table. Please refer to the the following code:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will update view-status of seen queries
 * limit value is read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['limit'])) 
{

    $limit = $_POST['limit'];

    //echo "limit= " . $limit;
    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    // mysql Updating view_status
    $result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_query_master t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT '".$limit."') as t2 on t1.query_id = t2.query_id SET t1.view_status=1");

    if($result)
    {
      // Record updated successfully
      $response["success"] = 1;
      $response["message"] = "Updated successfully.";
    }
   else
   {
        // Record updated successfully
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
   }

     // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);
}
else 
{
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

But for some unknown reason my update query above is not working and is giving me the  following error:

```
"{"success":0,"message":"Oops! An error occurred."}"
```

However, if I execute following query manually then it works perfectly.

```sql
  UPDATE tbl_query_master t1 
  INNER JOIN (SELECT query_id 
  FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 
  ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT 2) as t2 
  on t1.query_id = t2.query_id SET t1.view_status=1;
```

Comment: Have you checked whether the connection succeeds? Instead of printing your own error message try out with the actual error message

Comment: @ling.s Yes..! I have checked it.. there is no problem in connection. I think problem is on query line..

Comment: Could you please `var_dump` out `$result` straight after the query is executed and also [add the following line](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) `var_dump(mysqli_error())` and return it's output too, so it looks like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jujhars13/89bf3928fc03b8de5504).  This will give us better insight into the issue .

Comment: add `or die(mysqli_error($con)` after `mysqli_query()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change string

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_query_master t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT '".$limit."') as t2 on t1.query_id = t2.query_id SET t1.view_status=1");
```

to

```
$result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE tbl_query_master t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT ".$limit.") as t2 on t1.query_id = t2.query_id SET t1.view_status=1");
```

You don't need single quotes around `$limit` value.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested it.but hope it will help you it seems to be change on

```
 $result=mysqli_query('your query',$con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

```
$stm=mysqli_prepare($con,"UPDATE tbl_query_master t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT query_id FROM tbl_query_master WHERE view_status=0 ORDER BY query_date ASC LIMIT ?) as t2 on t1.query_id = t2.query_id SET t1.view_status=1");
                                                                                                                                                         ^
$stmt->bind_param('d', $limit);

/* execute prepared statement */
$stmt->execute();

printf("%d Row updated.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
```